Zeta Function Zeros and Dedekind Eta Function Integral
Working on algorithms related to number theoretical function calculation performance improvement and accidentally discovered the following for Dedekind $\eta$ function:
$$-\int_1^{\infty } \left(t^{-s-1}+t^{s-1}\right) \left(\frac{\pi  t}{12}+\log (\eta (i t))\right) \, dt=\frac{\Gamma (s) \zeta (s+1) \zeta (s)}{(2 \pi )^s}-\frac{(\pi -3) s^2+3}{6 s^2 \left(s^2-1\right)}$$
which may become interesting tool to investigate the zeros of $\zeta$-function.
I need a help in calculation of the left side integral effectively and understanding of the range of convergence of it.

I believe you have a sign problem as the numeric evaluation of the the left side differs in sign from evaluation of the right side for $s\in\mathbb{R}$.

@StevenClark thank you. Fixed this.
